# Should the parameters of a neural network be reset in each run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I am training a Graph Convolutional Network (GCN). My training code is as follows (the complete code is long so I put just the corresponding snippet):

```
for i in range(1, runs + 1):

        data = data.to(device)

        model.to(device).reset_parameters()
        
        optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=5e-4)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
        t_start = time.perf_counter()
        best_val_loss = float('inf')
        test_acc = 0
        
        for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
            
            train(model, optimizer, data)
            eval_info = evaluate(model, data)

            if eval_info['val_loss'] < best_val_loss:
                best_val_loss = eval_info['val_loss']
                test_acc = eval_info['test_acc']

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
        t_end = time.perf_counter()
```

My question is about resetting the parameters. If use `model.to(device)` instead of `model.to(device).reset_parameters()`, the mean accuracy of all runs (e.g. 10 runs) is around 5% higher than when I keep `model.to(device).reset_parameters()`. The validation losses of the two cases are nearly the same. I wonder whether I should reset the parameter in each run or not?

Comment: It depends on how you define a run. If you need them to be independent, then you have to reset the params.

Comment: @Berriel That is a fair point. My actual concern is if I consider the runs not independent, can that 5% increase in accuracy be the result of overfitting?